# Is a child directory "underneath" or "above"?

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems

Is there a defined rule when to use underneath and when to use above when describing a child directory? I have encountered (and used) both:

> Make sure the config file is stored above the web root.

(= outside the web root, *not* a child of it); also

> Underneath the images folder, I have three sub-folders: Photographs, Illustrations and Thumbnails.

But I have heard it being used the other way round, too:

> How to open files located under the webroot?

(referring to files outside the web root)

is there a correct one? Does this differ from OS to OS? How to avoid confusion?

Comment: I really don't understand your question. How does your examples contradict, exactly?

Comment: @Massimo I have seen the latter one refer to files *outside* (=above) the web root, hence my confusion. But the general consensus seems to be that "/home" is above "/home/htdocs"

Comment: @Pekka: I've never seen the last example used with this meaning... it just sounds "wrong".

Comment: That last example is just wrong. The author of the part you lifted it from is not clear in his or her intent. It's like you're asking if there's a proper way to refer to something when citing someone else who can't write clearly or properly.

Comment: ("Wrong" meaning it's not "outside the web root") The "proper" way to refer to something as a child file or child directory is to cite it in a clear manner to the majority of people attempting to follow directions.

Comment: You could also have a tree going from left to right (or right to left). The depiction doesn't really matter but generally, you'd say that the children were underneath.

Answer (score 15):

I have always known it as

- above = parent directory or higher
- below/under = child directory or subdirectory
- outside = anything not in a directory or child directory thereof

I have never heard otherwise.  Your two examples don't really contradict, either.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the examples. The way you show makes the most sense to me, too, and a cursory Googling places it way ahead.

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised that you would ask, actually.

The analogy is with depictions of family trees where the parents are shown above the children.

I too have never heard any other interpretation.

(if someone knows of a family tree shown with the parents *below* the children *it's upside down*)